# Использование line-clamp для родителя, обрезать текст у child

Tags: html, css

Есть такая необходимость с помощью line-clamp обрезать текст. Но нюанс что неизвестно сколько в родителя попадут абзацев и сколько строк в каждом будет, поэтому хотелось отслеживать строки у родителя, но у родителя это свойство получается не будет работать?

```
                    <div class="html__content">
                        <p>
                            И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира, 
                            которые представляют собой яркий пример континентально-европейского 
                            И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира, 
                            которые представляют собой яркий пример континентально-европейского
                            И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира, 
                            которые представляют собой яркий пример континентально-европейского 
                            И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира, 
                            которые представляют собой яркий пример континентально-европейского
                            И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира, 
                            которые представляют собой яркий пример континентально-европейского 
                            И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира, 
                            которые представляют собой яркий пример континентально-европейского
                            И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира
                        </p>
                    </div>
```

на примере хотелось бы в html__content обрезать текст на 8 строке уже. Но текст находится у детей. Если обращаться только к детям и обрезать на 4й строке то получается будет 2 места с многоточием у первого и второго абзаца. Вопрос в том можно ли как то применить данное свойство именно к родителю? То есть 5 строк от первого `<p>` и 3 строки от второго. Или этот вопрос по другому решается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только если сделать абзацы inline-элементами:

```css
.html__content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 8;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.html__content p {
  display: inline;
}
.html__content p::after {
  content:'\00000a'; 
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="html__content">
  <p>И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира, которые представляют собой яркий пример континентально-европейского И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира, которые представляют собой яркий пример континентально-европейского
И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира</p>

<p>И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира, которые представляют собой яркий пример континентально-европейского И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира, которые представляют собой яркий пример континентально-европейского
И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира</p>

<p>И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира, которые представляют собой яркий пример континентально-европейского И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира, которые представляют собой яркий пример континентально-европейского
И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Почему? У меня и абзацами отлично.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Да  inline элементом сделать не попробовал. Должно сейчас заработать. А абзацами сейчас раскрыл код, также не работает. У меня safari может поэтому. А второй вариант работает, спасибо!

Comment: Да шикарно работает с inline! Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Qwertiy в каком-то из относительно недавних релизов Хрома заработало, в Сафари и FF только к строчному содержимому применимо.

Answer (score 0):

А ты перед тем как задать вопрос, проверял? У меня всё работает:

```css
main {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 8;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира, которые представляют собой яркий пример континентально-европейского И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира, которые представляют собой яркий пример континентально-европейского
И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира</p>

  <p>И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира, которые представляют собой яркий пример континентально-европейского И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира, которые представляют собой яркий пример континентально-европейского
И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира</p>

  <p>И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира, которые представляют собой яркий пример континентально-европейского И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира, которые представляют собой яркий пример континентально-европейского
И нет сомнений, что активно развивающиеся страны третьего мира</p>
</main>
```